# Left join - SAS and oracle

Tags: oracle, sas, left-join

I'm trying to do a left join from a table I have in my SAS work libref and an extraction from Oracle but it gives an error message.

Here is my code:

```
PROC SQL;
connect to oracle(user=&usuario pass=&pass_dwhprd path='@dtm');
create table base_rateio1 (compress=yes reuse=yes) as
select B.* from connection to oracle
(select 
       A.*,
       substr(B.exem_cod_sog_scv,3,4)  projeto

  from       work.BASE_KPI3_2     A
  left join  exo_ing_ems@lkdwh    B 

where  exem_cod_cia >= 1
   and exem_cod_idt_fil >= 1
   and A.apolice  = B.exem_apo_num
   and A.contrato = B.exem_ctrs_cod
   and A.filial   = B.exem_cod_idt_fil
   and A.cod_cia  = B.exem_cod_cia
   and B.exem_ems_cod = 1
)
as t1;
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

And here is the error message:

```
 ERROR: ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00905: missing keyword. SQL statement: select A.*, substr(B.exem_cod_sog_scv,3,4) projeto from 
       work.BASE_KPI3_2 A, left join exo_ing_ems@lkdwh B where exem_cod_cia >= 1 and exem_cod_idt_fil >= 1 and A.apolice = 
       B.exem_apo_num and A.contrato = B.exem_ctrs_cod and A.filial = B.exem_cod_idt_fil and A.cod_cia = B.exem_cod_cia and 
       exem_ems_cod = 1.
```

I really don't know what is the problem

Comment: you cannot use  SAS work table in connect statement. You need to do implicit pass through or move SAS table to Oracle and then use the connect statement.

Comment: @Kiran There is no other way to do that? I don't have access/authorization to move SAS table to Oracle. That's why I'm trying this left join.

Comment: then you did not do an implicit pass through. See the third step in the answer below

Comment: From the above... you're missing an `ON` statement for your left join. based on the error :`ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connect statement does everything in oracle. So your query will not work within connect statement. You have two options. Either move SAS table to Oracle and then do joins as shown in next two steps

```
proc sql;
create table oratable.tablename as
select *
from sastable.tablename;
quit;
```

then use the above table in your query

```
  proc sql;
    connect to oracle (user=&myid orapw=&mypwd path="&mydb");
    execute ( use your logic here) by oracle; 
    disconnect from oracle;
    quit;
```

if above thing is not possible you have to do something like this.

```
 libname oratable oracle user=user password=password path=path; 

 proc sql;
    create table oratable.tablename as
    select *
    from sastable.tablename left join oratable.tablename
    on yourcolumns
    quit;
```

Comment: Might want to explicitly mention/show the `libname` syntax here, to make it more clear.

Comment: Joe, added libname syntax also as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You are using ANSI nomenclature to state your LEFT JOIN clause, therefore you should use the ON predicate to establish the relationship between the two tables, something like:

```
select B.* from connection to oracle
(select 
       A.*,
       substr(B.exem_cod_sog_scv,3,4)  projeto

  from       work.BASE_KPI3_2     A
  left join  exo_ing_ems@lkdwh    B ON A.apolice  = B.exem_apo_num
                                    and A.contrato = B.exem_ctrs_cod
                                   and A.filial   = B.exem_cod_idt_fil
                                   and A.cod_cia  = B.exem_cod_cia
                                   and B.exem_ems_cod = 1

where  exem_cod_cia >= 1
   and exem_cod_idt_fil >= 1
)
```

I don't know in which table the 'exem_cod_cia' and 'exem_cod_idt_fil' fields are, so if they are in B they could go in the 'ON' predicate as well, otherwise you could leave them there.